# Key "prototype" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony 3.3 contact form that sends an email, and I want to allow optional uploads of a few attachments.

I am attempting to adapt https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/form_collections.html to fit my needs.

The relevant part of my formBuilder looks like this:

```
        ->add('attachments', 'collection', array(
            'entry_type'   => FileType::class,
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'required'  => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
            ),
        ));
```

... and I have just modified my Twig template to look like this ...

```
<div>
    <ul class="attachments" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.attachments.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for attachment in form.attachments %}
        <li>{{ form_widget(attachment) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

... at which point a load of my page results in the following message:

> Key "prototype" for array with keys "value, attr, form, id, name,
>   full_name, disabled, label, label_format, multipart, block_prefixes,
>   unique_block_prefix, translation_domain, cache_key, errors, valid,
>   data, required, size, label_attr, compound, method, action, submitted,
>   sonata_admin_enabled, sonata_help, sonata_admin,
>   horizontal_label_class, horizontal_label_offset_class,
>   horizontal_input_wrapper_class, allow_add, allow_delete" does not
>   exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This may help you,please try refer the document:[Symfony form collection](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/form_collections.html)

```
<ul  data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.attachments.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype.name)|e }}
    ...
</ul>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <ul>
    {% for attachment in form.attachments %}
        <li>{{ form_row(attachment.name) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also refer this document

Answer (score 1):

Moving the `allow_add` property up a level did the trick. So I now have:

```
        ->add('attachments', 'collection', array(
            'entry_type'   => FileType::class,
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'required'  => false,
            ),
            'allow_add' => true,
        ));
```